# qpython android IOError: [Erno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-imaging-library, qpython

I am trying to call an image from a simple python script in qpython but get the error message:

```
qpython android IOError: [Erno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am wondering if I am using the correct directory convention? here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

spinner = {
        1: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/norm.jpg','r'),
        2: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/square.jpg','r'),
        3: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/fly.jpg','r'),
        4: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/tri.jpg','r'),
        5: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/special.jpg','r'),
        6: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/rect.jpg','r'),
        7: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/salad.jpg','r'),
        8: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/circle.jpg','r'),
        9: Image.open('storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/shapes/banana.jpg','r')
        }
```

It throws the same error without the 'r' argument. Also tried double fwd & back slashes...

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have not set the full path to your images it misses the slash at the beginning of the absolute path.

Try /storage/emulated..... Instead of storage/emulated ....