# 'No such file or directory' error Python for android

Tags: python-3.x, qpython3, pydroid

I have tried this on both Pydroid 3, and QPython3.

---

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46957757/7944165) which hasn't received an answer. I have a file saved in my internal storage, with the file path `/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx`, but if I run the code

```py
with open(r"/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx", "rb"):
    ...
```

...this gives a 'No such file or directory' error.

---

I tried to find solutions online, such as [this discussion](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1306398/how-can-i-access-files-r-or-w-from-a-script-using-qpython-on-android), but even running that gives exactly the same error. I have tried the same thing without the `r`, and with `//` instead of `/`, but this has not changed anything. There doesn't appear to be any such question on stackoverflow with any answer that works. I am able to run the code perfectly fine on my PC, but I am struggling to get my phone to find the file path.

Comment: what happens when you try `open(r"/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx", "rb")`  ?

Comment: It still comes up with the same error @sadap

Comment: so its a qpython problem and not a xlrd problem

Comment: @Sadap yes, I know. sorry if that wasn't clear. It is also a problem on Pydroid 3, though so that's why I think it might be something with file locations on android

Comment: Whether does it work with the below syntax ?
with open("/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx", "rb"):

Comment: @River no, that doesn't work either

Comment: Does this file /storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx really exist ?

Have you confirmed that the storange's read and write permissions are enabled?

Comment: @River I have a file with that name saved in that location, yes. I don't know about the read and write permissions and how to enable/disable them though - how can I check that?

Comment: I am using a Huawei phone, I can find the setting item under System Setting => Apps => Application Managers => QPython3 => Permissions.

Comment: @River Ahh yes, QPython3 does have Storage permissions enabled

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
import os
os.chdir("/storage/emulated/0")
with open("/qpython/projects3/filename.xlsx", "rb"):
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learning-python.com/cgi/showcode.py?name=android-tkinter/CODE/_openbrowser.py

Take away the with.

```
f  = open("names.txt", "r").read()

for line in f.split("\n"):

    print(line)
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work either - the same error happens here. I believe it was probably something wrong with the file location.